# Improvement to Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I was asked this question in an interview.

> If you had two numbers represented in the binary form and stored as a string. How would you perform simple addition. This was the easy part. (my solution: run through the shortest one and keep track of carry, repeat for the remaining)

The difficult part was when he asked me:

> how would you use hardware to make the process faster.

Any suggestion SO community?

Comment: I would suggest taking a peak at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry-lookahead_adder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say, convert them to proper integers, and use the hardware (ALU) to perform the addition, then convert the result back to a string if needed.

Comment: also remember that the binary form is tied to a particular endianess, this can be tricky sometimes because people forgot that and the difference between the data and its representation.

Answer (score 1):

Converting the numbers to an integer variable and letting the CPU do the addition immediately springs to mind. You can then divide the number back into bits if you so choose to.

Comment: What do you mean with "decimal integer". The computer presumably prefers working in binary ;-)

Comment: I don't think this would be any faster. You still have to loop through every character in the string to construct your binary representation of the numbers.